# Mex type C file to normal C file

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I have a c file written using mex functions, run by Matlab using mex compiler Now I want to run those mex type .c files without Matlab environment. So, is there any way to convert mex type .c file to normal .c file ? Or any other options available for the above mentioned concern.
Thanks in advance....!

Here is the one mex type .c file for sample.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "distances.h"
#include "ltl2tree.h"
#include "param.h"


#define BUFF_LEN 4096

char * emalloc(size_t n)
{       
    char *tmp;

    if (!(tmp = (char *) mxMalloc(n)))
        mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: not enough memory!");
    memset(tmp, 0, n);
    return tmp;
}

int tl_Getchar(int *cnt, size_t hasuform, char *uform)
{
    if (*cnt < hasuform)
        return uform[(*cnt)++];
    (*cnt)++;
    return -1;
}

void tl_UnGetchar(int *cnt)
{
    if (*cnt > 0) (*cnt)--;
}

#define Binop(a)        \
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, "(");  \
        dump(n->lft, miscell);      \
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, a);    \
        dump(n->rgt, miscell);      \
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, ")")

static void sdump(Node *n, char *dumpbuf)
{
    switch (n->ntyp) {
    case PREDICATE: strcat(dumpbuf, n->sym->name);
            break;
    case U_OPER:    strcat(dumpbuf, "U");
            goto common2;
    case V_OPER:    strcat(dumpbuf, "V");
            goto common2;
    case OR:    strcat(dumpbuf, "|");
            goto common2;
    case AND:   strcat(dumpbuf, "&");
common2:        sdump(n->rgt,dumpbuf);
common1:        sdump(n->lft,dumpbuf);
            break;
    case NEXT:  strcat(dumpbuf, "X");
            goto common1;
    case NOT:   strcat(dumpbuf, "!");
            goto common1;
    case TRUE:  strcat(dumpbuf, "T");
            break;
    case FALSE: strcat(dumpbuf, "F");
            break;
    default:    strcat(dumpbuf, "?");
            break;
    }
}

Symbol *DoDump(Node *n, char *dumpbuf, Miscellaneous *miscell)
{
    if (!n) return ZS;

    if (n->ntyp == PREDICATE)
        return n->sym;

    dumpbuf[0] = '\0';
    sdump(n,dumpbuf);
    return tl_lookup(dumpbuf, miscell);
}

void dump(Node *n, Miscellaneous *miscell)
{
    if (!n) return;

    switch(n->ntyp) {
    case OR:    Binop(" || "); break;
    case AND:   Binop(" && "); break;
    case U_OPER:    Binop(" U ");  break;
    case V_OPER:    Binop(" V ");  break;
    case NEXT:
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, "X");
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, " (");
        dump(n->lft, miscell);
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, ")");
        break;
    case NOT:
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, "!");
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, " (");
        dump(n->lft, miscell);
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, ")");
        break;
    case FALSE:
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, "false");
        break;
    case TRUE:
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, "true");
        break;
    case PREDICATE:
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, "(%s)", n->sym->name);
        break;
    case -1:
        fprintf(miscell->tl_out, " D ");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Unknown token: ");
        tl_explain(n->ntyp);
        break;
    }
}

void tl_explain(int n)
{
    switch (n) {
    case ALWAYS:    printf("[]"); break;
    case EVENTUALLY: printf("<>"); break;
    case IMPLIES:   printf("->"); break;
    case EQUIV: printf("<->"); break;
    case PREDICATE: printf("predicate"); break;
    case OR:    printf("||"); break;
    case AND:   printf("&&"); break;
    case NOT:   printf("!"); break;
    case U_OPER:    printf("U"); break;
    case V_OPER:    printf("V"); break;
    case NEXT:  printf("X"); break;
    case TRUE:  printf("true"); break;
    case FALSE: printf("false"); break;
    case ';':   printf("end of formula"); break;
    default:    printf("%c", n); break;
    }
}

static void non_fatal(char *s1, char *s2, int *cnt, char *uform, int *tl_yychar, Miscellaneous *miscell)
{
    int i;

    printf("TaLiRo: ");
    if (s2)
        printf(s1, s2);
    else
        printf(s1);
    if ((*tl_yychar) != -1 && (*tl_yychar) != 0)
    {   printf(", saw '");
        tl_explain((*tl_yychar));
        printf("'");
    }
    printf("\nTaLiRo: %s\n---------", uform);
    for (i = 0; i < (*cnt); i++)
        printf("-");
    printf("^\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    (miscell->tl_errs)++;
}

void
tl_yyerror(char *s1, int *cnt, char *uform, int *tl_yychar, Miscellaneous *miscell)
{
    Fatal(s1, (char *) 0, cnt, uform, tl_yychar, miscell);
}

void
Fatal(char *s1, char *s2, int *cnt, char *uform, int *tl_yychar, Miscellaneous *miscell)
{
  non_fatal(s1, s2, cnt, uform, tl_yychar, miscell);
  tl_exit(0);
}

void fatal(char *s1, char *s2, int *cnt, char *uform, int *tl_yychar, Miscellaneous *miscell)
{
        non_fatal(s1, s2, cnt, uform, tl_yychar, miscell);
        tl_exit(0);
}

void put_uform(char *uform, Miscellaneous *miscell)
{
    fprintf(miscell->tl_out, "%s", uform);
}

void tl_exit(int i)
{
    mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: unexpected error, tl_exit executed.");
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{   
    /* Variables needed to process the input */
    int status, pstatus;
    mwSize buflen, pbuflen;
    size_t NElems,NCells;
    mwSize ndimA, ndimb, ndimG, ndim, pdim,ndimP;
    const mwSize *dimsA, *dimsb, *dimsG, *dims, *pardims,*dimsP;
    mwIndex jstruct, iii, jjj, i1, j1, idx_j;
    mxArray *tmp,*tmp1,*tmp_cell;   
    /* Variables needed for monitor */
    Node *node;
    double *XTrace, *TStamps, *LTrace;
    DistCompData distData;
    PMap *predMap; 
    int ii,jj,kk,ll,objs,tempI;
    bool par_on;
    bool is_Multi_HA;
    bool initial_of_par;
    int npred, npar;

    static char uform[BUFF_LEN];
    static size_t hasuform=0;
    static int *cnt;
    int temp = 0;
    Miscellaneous *miscell = (Miscellaneous *) emalloc(sizeof(Miscellaneous));
    int *tl_yychar = (int *) emalloc(sizeof(int));
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.LTL = 1; 
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.ConOnSamples = 0; 
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.SysDim = 0; 
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.nSamp = 0; 
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.nPred = 0; 
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.true_nPred = 0; 
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.tnLoc = 0; 
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.nInp = 0; 
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.nCLG = 0;
    miscell->tl_errs = 0;
    miscell->type_temp = 0;

    /* Reset cnt to 0:
        cnt is the counter that points to the next symbol in the formula
        to be processed. This is a static variable and it retains its 
        value between Matlab calls to mx_dp_taliro. */
    cnt = &temp;

    /* Other initializations */
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.nInp = nrhs;
    par_on = false;
    initial_of_par = false;
    npred = 0;
    npar= 0;

    /* Make sure the I/O are in the right form */
    if(nrhs < 3)
        mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: At least 3 inputs are required.");
    else if(nlhs > 1)
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: Too many output arguments.");
    else if(nrhs > 8)
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: Too many input arguments.");
    else if(!mxIsChar(prhs[0]))
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: 1st input must be a string with TL formula.");
    else if(!mxIsStruct(prhs[1]))
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: 2nd input must be a structure (predicate map).");
    else if(!mxIsDouble(prhs[2]))
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: 3rd input must be a numerical array (State trace).");
    else if(nrhs>3 && !mxIsDouble(prhs[3]))
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: 4th input must be a numerical array (Time stamps).");
    else if(nrhs>5 && !mxIsDouble(prhs[4]))
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: 5th input must be a numerical array (Location trace).");
    else if(nrhs>5 && !(mxIsDouble(prhs[5])||mxIsCell(prhs[5])))
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: 6th input must be a numerical array \n (Minimum path distance to each control location for each predicate).");
    else if(nrhs>7 && !(mxIsCell(prhs[6])))
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: 7th input must be a cell array (Adjacency list).");
    else if(nrhs>7 && !(mxIsStruct(prhs[7])||mxIsCell(prhs[7])))
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: 8th input must be a structure (guard map).");

    if(nlhs > 1)
        mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments.");
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);

    /* Process inputs */

    /* Get the formula */
    ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0]);
    dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
    buflen = dims[1]*sizeof(mxChar)+1;
    if (buflen >= BUFF_LEN)
    {
      mexPrintf("%s%d%s\n", "The formula must be less than ", BUFF_LEN," characters.");
      mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: Formula too long.");
    }
    status = mxGetString(prhs[0], uform, buflen);   
    hasuform = strlen(uform);
    for (iii=0; iii<hasuform; iii++)
    {
        if (uform[iii] == '\t' || uform[iii] == '\"' || uform[iii] == '\n')                     
            uform[iii] = ' ';
    }

    /* Get state trace */       
    ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[2]);
    if (ndim>2)
        mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: The state trace is not in proper form!"); 
    dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[2]);
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.nSamp = dims[0];
    miscell->dp_taliro_param.SysDim = dims[1];
    XTrace = mxGetPr(prhs[2]);

    /* Get time stamps */      
    if (nrhs>3)
    {
        ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[3]);
        if (ndim>2)
            mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: The time stamp sequence is not in proper form!"); 
        dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[3]);
        if (miscell->dp_taliro_param.nSamp != dims[0])
            mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: The lengths of the time stamp sequence and the state trace do not match!"); 
        TStamps = mxGetPr(prhs[3]);
    }

    /* Get location trace and location graph */    
    if (nrhs>4)
    {
        ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[4]);
        if (ndim>2)
            mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: The location trace is not in proper form!"); 
        dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[4]);
        if (miscell->dp_taliro_param.nSamp != dims[0])
            mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: The lengths of the location trace and the state trace do not match!"); 
        LTrace = mxGetPr(prhs[4]);

        /* For Multiple H.A.s is added  */
        if(nrhs>5 && (mxIsCell(prhs[5]))){/*  For Multiple H.A.s */
            is_Multi_HA=1;
        miscell->dp_taliro_param.nCLG = dims[1];
            ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[5]);
            if (ndim>2)
            {
                mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro.c: !"); 
            }
            dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[5]);
            if (dims[0]!=1)
            {
                mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: DMin is a cell, it must be a column vector cell!"); 
            }
            if (dims[1]!=miscell->dp_taliro_param.nCLG)
            {
                mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: DMin is a cell, it must be of the size of nCLG!"); 
            }
            distData.LDistNCLG = (double **)emalloc((miscell->dp_taliro_param.nCLG)*sizeof(double*));
            miscell->dp_taliro_param.tnLocNCLG = (mwSize*)emalloc((miscell->dp_taliro_param.nCLG)*sizeof(mwSize));
            for(kk=0; kk<miscell->dp_taliro_param.nCLG; kk++){
                tmp = mxGetCell(prhs[5],kk);
                dims = mxGetDimensions(tmp);
                miscell->dp_taliro_param.tnLocNCLG[kk] = dims[0];
                distData.LDistNCLG[kk]=mxGetPr(tmp);
            }
        }
        else if(nrhs>5) {/*  For Single H.A. */
            is_Multi_HA=0;
            ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[5]);
            if (ndim>2)
                mexErrMsgTxt("mx_dp_taliro: The minimum distance array is not in proper form!"); 
            dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[5]);
            miscell->dp_taliro_param.tnLoc = dims[0];
            distData.LDist = mxGetPr(prhs[5]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please share your sample code? I think there are several possivilities to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @bushmills, I have added a part of mex type .c code. I want to convert this mex type .c code to normal .c code, without the use of mex functions. Please suggest the possible ways that I can look for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using a lot of functions and data types, provided by the MEX API. Therefore, if you want to produce "normal" C-Code you will have to completly refactor your code.

But one possible solution might be to compile your source code outside MATLAB IDE, by gcc or any other compiler. In this case you will have to include all necessary header files and link against all libraries you need.
Follwo the link to find a pretty good documentation from Mathworks:

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/377799-compiling-mex-files-without-the-mex-command

Another way for creating C Code from Matlab Scipts/Functions is to use MATLAB Coder:

https://de.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi @bushmills, I have gone through the above mentioned links. In the first link they are making again the compiled file with the extension .mexw64 which can only be run in Matlab. In second video the Matlab Coder doesn't take input .c files, it takes only .m and .mlx files to convert into equivalent .c/.c++ file. 
My aim is to run these mex type .c files without Matlab environment. 
Please help.